# How to set many variables in 1 line?

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to set this but that not working:

```
$surname = $_SESSION['surname'], $gender = $_SESSION['gender'], $age = $_SESSION['age'];
```

Any idea?

Comment: Change the comma to a semicolon?

Comment: Or put each on its own line which I believe most people would say is much more readable.

Comment: Please stahp putting all variables in one line. If I had to maintain your code after you then I would have a justified reason to hate a person I've never met. Terminate with a semi-colon and declare each variable on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Statements in PHP are terminated by `;` (while in Javascript a statement can be terminated with a new line as well), so if you want to display them on a single line - just do what you'd always do and display them on the same line by removing the line breaks:

```
$surname = $_SESSION['surname']; $gender = $_SESSION['gender']; $age = $_SESSION['age'];
```

.. but having a single line for each assignment is the recommended coding style, as can help to avoid hiding subtle bugs:

```
$surname = $_SESSION['surname']; 
$gender = $_SESSION['gender']; 
$age = $_SESSION['age'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use semicolon(;) instead of (,) as shown below

> $surname = $_SESSION['surname']; $gender = $_SESSION['gender']; $age =
>   $_SESSION['age'];

Answer (score 0):

**Sessions** are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID.

Sessions follow a simple workflow. **When a session is started**, PHP will either retrieve an existing session using the ID passed (usually from a session cookie) or if no session is passed it will create a new session. PHP will populate the *`$_SESSION`* superglobal with any session data after the session has started. When PHP shuts down, it will automatically take the contents of the `$_SESSION` superglobal, serialize it, and send it for storage using the session save handler.

> Example #1 Registering a variable with $_SESSION.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
```

> In Your case code should be:

```
<?php    
    session_start();
    $surname = $_SESSION['surname']; $gender = $_SESSION['gender']; $age = $_SESSION['age'];
   ?>
```